# streaming data to opentsdb

Tags: streaming, hbase, opentsdb

I have played a bit with opentsdb each time reading data from a txt file and writing it to a .txt file.
Is there a way to bypass the .txt file i.e. streaming some data directly to opentsdb?

I have seen the implementation with tcollector but I am looking for something more general that would scale with some pretty large data.
thanks for you help.
Philippe C.

ps I am as specific as I can but I know it isn't really clear if you have any questions that I haven't thought of, ask away!

Answer (score 0):

The general way to get data into openTSDB is to use the [HTTP Put api](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/put.html).

To scale with large amounts of data, you can have multiple openTSDB servers in a cluster and round robin the data between them with a http load balancer.